# HttpServletRequest get JSON POST data

Tags: java, json, post, servlets

I am HTTP POST-ing to URL http://laptop:8080/apollo/services/rpc?cmd=execute

with
POST data

```json
{ "jsondata" : "data" }
```

Http request has Content-Type of `application/json; charset=UTF-8`

How do I get the POST data (jsondata) from HttpServletRequest?

If I enumerate the request params, I can only see one param,
which is "cmd", not the POST data.

Comment: This is simple method to get request data `request.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining())`

Comment: the above mentioned throws stream already closed exception

Comment: If you use the `getReader()` the stream will get closed, since originally it can only be read once. There are a number of alternatives on Wrapper implementations to allow multiple calls to `getReader()`

Comment: The easiest way you can solve this is using *Jackson*'s `ObjectMapper`. Its overloaded method `readValue` has a variation which accepts a `Reader` and a `Class<T>`. What you end up with is:
`new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getReader(), YourBodyType.class)` - and there you have it. Short and slick.

Answer (score 282):

Normaly you can GET and POST parameters in a servlet the same way:

```
request.getParameter("cmd");
```

**But only if the POST data is [encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)) as key-value pairs of content type: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" like when you use a standard HTML form.**

If you use a different encoding schema for your post data, as in your case when you post a *json data stream*, you need to use a custom decoder that can process the raw datastream from:

```
BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
```

**Json post processing example (uses [org.json](http://www.json.org/) package )**

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  throws ServletException, IOException {

  StringBuffer jb = new StringBuffer();
  String line = null;
  try {
    BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
      jb.append(line);
  } catch (Exception e) { /*report an error*/ }

  try {
    JSONObject jsonObject =  HTTP.toJSONObject(jb.toString());
  } catch (JSONException e) {
    // crash and burn
    throw new IOException("Error parsing JSON request string");
  }

  // Work with the data using methods like...
  // int someInt = jsonObject.getInt("intParamName");
  // String someString = jsonObject.getString("stringParamName");
  // JSONObject nestedObj = jsonObject.getJSONObject("nestedObjName");
  // JSONArray arr = jsonObject.getJSONArray("arrayParamName");
  // etc...
}
```

Comment: It seems like you can only get the post data from request.getReader *once*. Is this true? When I tried this myself, subsequent calls to get the post-data of the request fail.

Comment: That's correct you can read the request body content only once.

Comment: this really saved my day...but what is getReader and how do the json data get populated there? is it specifically for JSON? or any other object ? any helpful links please.

Comment: Why not just to pass `getReader()` to json parser as here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15109169/603516 ? This wouldn't require extra copy loop.

Comment: JSONObject jsonObject =   HTTP.toJSONObject(jb.toString());

toJSONObject must have been moved to be a static method in the org.json.HTTP class

Comment: Why I cannot find the `fromObject(String string)` method inside the documentation? http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html

Comment: @X.Li, see the comment directly above yours.

Comment: You can use StringBuilder here, and you need close reader in finally block. Just in case :)

Comment: Should be: JSONObject jsonObject =  new JSONObject(jb.toString());

Comment: get POST body `BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();`

Answer (score -3):

Are you posting from a different source (so different port, or hostname)? If so, this very very recent topic I just answered might be helpful.

- [Odd jQuery problem - Ajax request to a C program not quite working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831255/odd-jquery-problem-ajax-request-to-a-c-program-not-quite-working)

The problem was the XHR Cross Domain Policy, and a useful tip on how to get around it by using a technique called JSONP. The big downside is that JSONP does not support POST requests.

*I know in the original post there is no mention of JavaScript, however JSON is usually used for JavaScript so that's why I jumped to that conclusion*