# Retrieving jsonData in servlet

Tags: java, json, servlets, extjs, extjs4

I am using Extjs 4 and Java Servlets in my app. I want to post some data to the server in json format.

The format of JSON should be like this:

```
{
    "credentials":[
    {
       "username":"george",
       "password":"xyz"
    }
    ]
}
```

I did this in extjs code:

```
buttons: [{
        text: 'Submit',
        handler: function() {               
            Ext.Ajax.request({
                url: '/Model/FormServlet',
                method: 'POST',
                jsonData : {
                    //Hardcoded values
                    username: "george", 
                    password: "xyz"
                },
                callback: function (options, success, response) {                       
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        }           
    }]
```

1)  I believe that I wont get the JSON format which I posted above. Please let me know how to get that format using `jsonData`.

2) How to retrieve this in servlet doPost method? Since I have not used `params` and have replaced it with `jsonData` hence `request.getParameter` is not going to work in the servlet `doPost` method.

Please let me know how to make this work.

Regards,

Comment: use gson http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: try aading this in params 
`params : Ext.encode({credentials:[{username:'george',password:'xyz'}]})` in Ajax request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You are OK

2) This is a POST request; the data will not come in a parameter (e.g. not multipart/form-data) but will be the content of the HTTP request. In `doPost`, simply read everything in `request.getInputStream()` and transform it to String using the proper encoding or call `request.getContent()` directly if you have a proper `ContentHandler` registered.

Something along the lines of

```
byte[] ba = IOUtils.toByteArray( req.getInputStream(  ) );
String charset = TypedContentUtils.extractCharset( req.getContentType(  ) );
String json = new String( ba, charset );
```

`IOUtils` is Apache Commons IO (writing your own is 10 lines with proper Exception handling); `TypedContentUtils.extractCharset` is a simple home grown method extracting the charset from the Content-Type or defaulting to utf-8.

Comment: Ok this post was helpful I solved the problem using the code posted below. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

I tried this bit of code in doPost method and it worked:

```
StringBuffer jb = new StringBuffer();
      String line = null;
      try {
        BufferedReader reader = req.getReader();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
          jb.append(line);
        System.out.println(jb.toString());
      } catch (Exception e) { 
          e.printStackTrace();        
      }
```

Reference article:

[HttpServletRequest get JSON POST data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831680/httpservletrequest-get-post-data)

Answer (score 2):

1) It will post the data as it is. The content will be : { username: "george", password: "xyz"}, if you want the format above and it is hardcoded then you can juste replace it.

2) You can easily deserialize your json into a java object with genson library http://code.google.com/p/genson/.

```
UserCredentials userCredentials = new Genson().deserialize(request.getReader(), UserCredentials.class);
```

Comment: Firstly, I dont want to use any third party library. Secondly, The problem is with retrieving the JSON in a servlet. Once I am able to retrieve it in servlet doPost, I can deserialize it into java object using some utility methods already present in my app workspace.

Comment: @user182944 Ok, to retrieve the json content use request.getReader() or request.getInputStream() (both work)

Comment: Thanks for the help. It really showed me pointers towards right direction.