# Receiving NULL in parameter when passing from js to Servlet.

Tags: javascript, servlets, parameters

I am getting null when trying to receive parameter from JavaScript. I have gone through few post, but could not figure out where i am making the mistake in my code.

Below is code from where i am sending request:

```
function funcOnChange() {
    var index = document.detail.Class.selectedIndex;
    var valueSelected = document.detail.Class.options[index].value;

    handleRequestStateChange = function()
    {
        // Check to see if this state change was "request complete", and
        // there was no server error (404 Not Found, 500 Server Error, etc)
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) 
        {
            var substring=xmlHttp.responseText;
            alert("Alert Dialog! Gaurav");
        }
    }
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost:8080/ReportFetcher/FormHandler', true);
    xhr.send(valueSelected);
}
```

I am getting the `valueselected` from the following piece of code and `valueselected`'s is correct:

```
<select name="Class" onchange="funcOnChange()">
            <option value="None">None</option>
            <option value="FIRST">FIRST</option>
            <option value="SECOND">SECOND</option>
            <option value="THIRD">THIRD</option>
            <option value="FOURTH">FOURTH</option>
            <option value="FIFTH">FIFTH</option>
            <option value="SIXTH">SIXTH</option>
            <option value="SEVENTH">SEVENTH</option>
            <option value="EIGHTH">EIGHTH</option>
            <option value="NINTH">NINTH</option>
            <option value="TENTH">TENTH</option>
        </select><br>
```

I am receiving a callback on onPost() of FormHandler.java

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    log.info("IN form doPost");
    String selectedClass = request.getParameter("Class");
    log.info(selectedClass);

}
```

Problem:    `selectedClass` is null here.

Suggest where i am making mistake.

Comment: I think there is some issue with key-value mapping, but could not find out where problem is occurring. Also, i tried passing value using GET request and i got the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
function funcOnChange() {
    var index = document.detail.Class.selectedIndex;
    var valueSelected = "Class="+document.detail.Class.options[index].text;

    .....
    .....

    xhr.send(valueSelected);
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, is there exist a better way to define key for the valueSelected .

Comment: I think no, key will be accessed in Servlet so manually we need to sepicify some Key

Comment: No, i think there was some compilation or refresh issue. But this way is not working. I restarted the server and compiled it again. So I was not getting the parameter. So please suggest some other way out.

Comment: If you want to read the data without key value try HTTPServletRequest getReader interface. Though I will recommend not to use it. 
An example is provided in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831680/httpservletrequest-get-post-data

Answer (score 0):

If you see through any proxy/ HTTP monitor tool ( I use Charles) your requests and responses you will see that you are not sending the request as key value pairs ( in simple terms you are not sending Class=value) but you are sending only the value of Class attribute as string. (i.e. Third if you select the option Third in the select box). You need to send the [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/FormData) if you want to read data on server as key value pairs.

```
function funcOnChange() {
    var index = document.detail.Class.selectedIndex;
    var valueSelected = document.detail.Class.options[index].value;

    handleRequestStateChange = function()
    {
        // Check to see if this state change was "request complete", and
        // there was no server error (404 Not Found, 500 Server Error, etc)
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) 
        {
            var substring=xmlHttp.responseText;
            alert("Alert Dialog! Gaurav");
        }
    }
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'http://fiddle.jshell.net/', true);    
    var form = new FormData();
    form.append("Class",valueSelected)
    xhr.send(form);
}
```