# Getting post data from HttpServletRequest multiple times

Tags: java, spring

I want to create a logger that put's all the post data into my logfile. I added a interceptor to Spring and added all the necessary stuff to the `preHandle` method where I am reading out the post data (most of the time it is raw json in my case)

```
final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(128);
if (request.getMethod().equals("POST")) {
    sb.append("] [data=");
    StringBuffer jb = new StringBuffer();
    String line = null;
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        jb.append(line);
        reader.reset();
    } catch (Exception e) { 
    }
    sb.append(jb.toString());
}
```

Most of the code is taken from [HttpServletRequest get JSON POST data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831680/httpservletrequest-get-post-data) where you can read from the comments that you can only read out the post data once! If you do that before the request is finalized you get an exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: READER
```

How can I read out the POST data from the request without breaking any further actions?

Comment: Provide more of the stacktrace.

Comment: do you really need the stacktrace, since the reason for the exception is well known, as you can read in the comments of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831680/httpservletrequest-get-post-data

Comment: If you think this is a duplicate,  please delete you question.

Comment: I already flagged for moderation ... I think it is valid to leave it here as a reference to the other one