# Big Json data in Java servlet

Tags: java, mysql, ajax, json, post

I work with java servlets and I want to receive Big json data from client.

my client code is

```
 url: "http://localhost:8080/JsonTest/setJson",
 type: "POST",
 dataType: 'json',
 contentType: 'application/json',
 data:{json:str},
```

my server code is

```
String json=request.getParameter("json");
```

but json variable is `null`

Can anybody help me?

Comment: The JSON will be written in the body. Use the `getInputStream` method of the `HttpServletRequest` to read the JSON from the request body. Then use a JSON parser to parse it.

Comment: example of what you want to do is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831680/httpservletrequest-get-post-data

Answer (score 0):

try JSON.stringify on the data:

```
url: "http://localhost:8080/JsonTest/setJson",
type: "POST",
dataType: 'json',
contentType: 'application/json',
data: JSON.stringify({json:str}),
```

or if str is already a json string:

```
url: "http://localhost:8080/JsonTest/setJson",
type: "POST",
dataType: 'json',
contentType: 'application/json',
data: str,
```

Comment: well, did it fix your issue?