# How to submit additional data along the file upload in dropzone.js?

Tags: javascript, forms, dropzone.js

I have this form in my html code:

```
<form action="upload" id="upload-dropzone" class="dropzone">
    <input type="hidden" name="browser-path" id="browser-path" value="/">

    <div class="browser-buttons rrtl">
        <a id="browser-btn-upload">Upload</a>
    </div>

    <div class="lltr" id="browser-path-view"></div>
</form>

<script type="application/javascript">
    Dropzone.options.uploadDropzone = {
        clickable: "#browser-btn-upload",
    };
    loadBrowserContent();
</script>
```

As [this document](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/FAQ#how-to-submit-additional-data-along-the-file-upload) said, the hidden input field `browser-path` will automatically be submitted as POST data to server.

I have this code in my server side:

```
System.out.println(request.getParameter("browser-path"));
```

But this code always prints `null` to output!

How can I submit this hidden field to my server and how can I read it?

**Edit:**

Thanks to steeno, the form `enctype` is `multipart/form-data` so I have to read the fields from another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you use Java as backend language?

As mentioned in the following question: [HttpServletRequest get JSON POST data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831680/httpservletrequest-get-post-data)
the problem yould be the encoding of the post request. Maybe try to get the post data with [getReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getReader()) instead of `getParameter`.