# Servlet request.getParameter return null

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, servlets

On the web page, I use JQuery to send Ajax call to my servlet.

```
function sendAjax() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/AddOrUpdateServlet",
                type: 'POST',   
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {"name": "hello world"},
                contentType: 'application/json',
                mimeType: 'application/json',

                success: function (data) {   

                },
                error:function(data,status,er) {
                    alert("error: "+data+" status: "+status+" er:"+er);
                }
            });         
        }
```

In the AddOrUpdateServlet's doPost, I have the following code:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
    String name = request.getParameter("name"); 
    if (name == null) 
        System.out.println("null"); 

    /*
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().write(new Integer(1).toString());
    response.getWriter().close();
    */

}
```

I can see the parameter was successfully sent and received by the servlet as the console printed out "null". But why was the servlet unable to get the "name" param?

Comment: Why are you setting `mimeType: 'application/json',`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have passed the `"name"` parameter in `request body of POST`,and more over it is `JSON` type.

Just make it `GET` request  and remove the below line

```
`contentType: 'application/json',mimeType: 'application/json',
```

**EDIT:--** write below line of code in your servlet,you will have to use JSON library,to parse the data in your servlet(`GSON or Jackson`)
   See :-  [Stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831680/httpservletrequest-get-post-data)

```
StringBuffer jb = new StringBuffer();
  String line = null;
  try {
    BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
      jb.append(line);
  } catch (Exception e) { /*report an error*/ }

  try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = JSONObject.fromObject(jb.toString());
  } catch (ParseException e) {
    // crash and burn
    throw new IOException("Error parsing JSON request string");
  }
```

Comment: But I still want to use POST instead of GET. How?

Comment: updated my answer with reference to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831680/httpservletrequest-get-post-data, in this case you do not have to change your method.

Comment: Thanks RE350. I think I am nearly there. But the problem is JQuery sent "name=hello+world" instead of the original JSON data {"name": "hello world"}. I think it was automatically transformed.

Comment: change the below line data: {"name": "hello world"},  to data: JSON.stringify({"name": "hello world"}),