# How I send the result of the AJAX back to the JSP?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, servlets

I post some via AJAX in my servet from my jsp

```
$.ajax({                    
    url: 'myServlet?action=FEP',
    type: 'post',
    data: {machine: i, name: txt}, // i, txt have some values.
    success: function (data) {
        alert('success');
    }
});
```

and in my Serlvlet

```
String jspAction = request.getParameter("action");

//...

if(jspAction.equals("FEP")){
    int idMachine = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("machine")); 
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    double value = actions.getValue(idMachine, name); //<-- this variable I want to send it back to the JSP.
}
```

The data are sent succesfully. However I haven't understand how I send back the `vaule` to the jsp..

Comment: could you clarify your problem? Which "value" are you referring to? You can access all GET and POST parameters via `request.getParameter("variable")`, take care to use the [right form encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831680/httpservletrequest-get-post-data) though

Comment: I have defined a variable as `value`.

Comment: I want the variable `value` to send it back to the JSP.

Comment: The same way you send any data back to the browser.

Comment: I send via session `session.setAttribute("value", value);`. How i will read then this variable from the javascript??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

returning a string would go as follows:

```
response.getWriter().write("a string");
return null;
```

If you want to return json, you can use many libraries like: http://www.json.org/

This would result in something like following code:

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
double aDouble = 38d;
jsonObject.put("returnValue", aDouble);
response.getWriter().write(jsonObject.toString());
return null;
```

Comment: it's a double the returning value

Comment: you can set the double as a value in your jsonObject

Answer (score 0):

Use
    `response.getWriter().write(value);
 return null;`

And in your ajax success block access the value. 
See the following link for more understanding http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/09/jquery-ajax-servlets-integration-building-a-complete-application.html