# How to send canvas png image to java servlet using ajax?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, servlets, canvas

I am trying to send a canvas PNG to a java servlet using ajax.
Here is my javascript code:

```
function sendToServer(image){   
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "SaveAnnotation",
    data: {
        annotationImage: image
        },
    success: function(msg)
    {                       
            alert(msg);
    },
    error: function()
    {
        alert("Error connecting to server!");
    }
}); 
}

function save() {
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
sendToServer(dataURL);
}
```

And the java servlet doPost():

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/plain");      
    try{
        String img64 = request.getParameter("annotationImage");
        byte[] decodedBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(img64);
        BufferedImage bfi = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedBytes));    
        File outputfile = new File("saved_annotations/saved.png");
        ImageIO.write(bfi , "png", outputfile);
        bfi.flush();   
        out.print("Success!");
    }catch(IOException e){  
          out.print(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The problem is that `getParameter("annotationImage")` returns `null`, and I can't understand why: using browser debugger I can see `annotationImage`and its value between the request parameters, so I am sure it is not null, but for some reason the parameter is not received by the Java Servlet.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831680/httpservletrequest-get-json-post-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the reasons why it didn't work. 
To avoid parsing JSON I send the data to the server without setting any parameter, writing `data: image` instead of JSON formatted `data: {annotationImage: image}` to avoid JSON parsing in the servlet.

In the java servlet I get the entire request body, remove the content-type declaration and finally decode and save the image. Here is the code:

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    response.setContentType("text/plain");

    StringBuffer jb = new StringBuffer();
    String line = null;
    BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        jb.append(line);

    String img64 = jb.toString();   
    //check if the image is really a base64 png, maybe a bit hard-coded
    if(img64 != null && img64.startsWith("data:image/png;base64,")){
        //Remove Content-type declaration
        img64 = img64.substring(img64.indexOf(',') + 1);            
    }else{
        response.setStatus(403);
        out.print("Formato immagine non corretto!");
        return;
    }   
    try{
        InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.getDecoder().decode(img64.getBytes()));  
        BufferedImage bfi = ImageIO.read(stream);
        String path = getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRealPath("saved_annotations/saved.png");
        File outputfile = new File(path);
        outputfile.createNewFile();
        ImageIO.write(bfi , "png", outputfile);
        bfi.flush();
        response.setStatus(200);
        out.print("L'immagine e' stata salvata con successo!");         
    }catch(IOException e){  
        e.printStackTrace();
        response.setStatus(500);
        out.print("Errore durante il salvataggio dell'immagine: " + e.getMessage());      
    }
}
```