# Difference between reading jsp data on servlet from BufferedReader (request.getInputStream()) and request.getParameter

Tags: java, ajax, servlets, sling

Below is my ajax call:-

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/bin/commersenext/assetUpload',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType:'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify(ob),
            dataType: 'json',
          success:function(msg){
            alert("data"+msg);
              console.log(msg);
            }

        });
```

and  when trying to read the data

```
String tabledata = request.getParameter("data");
```

getting null pointer exp.

But if i use below line of code m able to read the data.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream()));
```

Comment: The problem is in your datatype and data parameters, try removing the datatype attribute and see the result.

Answer (score 1):

You can only get the POST data if it is encoded as key-value pairs of content type: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

otherwise use a BufferedReader see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3831791/2310289