# How do I read the post data in a Spring Boot Controller?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I would like to read POST data from a Spring Boot controller.

I have tried all the solutions given here: [HttpServletRequest get JSON POST data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831680/httpservletrequest-get-json-post-data), but I still am unable to read post data in a Spring Boot servlet.

My code is here:

```
package com.testmockmvc.testrequest.controller;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

@Controller
public class TestRequestController {

    @RequestMapping(path = "/testrequest")
    @ResponseBody
    public String testGetRequest(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
        final byte[] requestContent;
        requestContent = IOUtils.toByteArray(request.getReader());
        return new String(requestContent, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }
}
```

I have tried using the Collectors as an alternative, and that does not work either. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I always get a zero length content. If I debug the code, I can see the post data in the servlet request object, but somehow it does not get read.

Comment: get requests don't have a body, do they?

Comment: Clarification: This is for a post (not specifying the method allows both GET and POST)

Comment: I'm just saying should you call it with a get!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you need to define the RequestMethod as POST.
Second, you can define a @RequestBody annotation in the String parameter

```
@Controller
public class TestRequestController {

    @RequestMapping(path = "/testrequest", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String testGetRequest(@RequestBody String request) throws IOException {
        final byte[] requestContent;
        requestContent = IOUtils.toByteArray(request.getReader());
        return new String(requestContent, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding the "method=RequestMethod.POST" did not make any difference. I cannot add the "@ResponseBody" as an annotation to the parameter. I can only add it as an annotation to the method itself.

Comment: I just adjusted the answer.. adding the RequestBody instead of ResponseBody annotation, my mistake.

Comment: Quick update: I was using the same method for handling GET and POST requests, but adding the RequestBody annotation required me to have two different methods, one for GET and another for POST.