# How to receive form parameters values in server?

Tags: java, server, httprequest, axios

i have React JS application where i send post request to server with form submission using axios library.

client request:

```
sendData(data,price) {
    axios.post('http://localhost:8080/SampleJavaAPP/UserServer', {
    item: data,//these value
    price:price//these value
  })
  .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
  }
```

i am not sure how to get these values into server i am doing in server for getting value like this

```
String name = request.getParameter("item");
        String price = request.getParameter("price");

        System.out.println("Result "+name + price);
```

But it gives null values in server. how to receive these values parameters in server?

Comment: Have you tried console.log(data, price) just before your post request, to clarify where the issue comes from?

Comment: yes values are printing in console but it gives null in the server...

Comment: What are you using to write your server-side software? Note that it does not matter that you make the request with React. All clients will make the HTTP request in the exact same way no matter what language or framework they use.

Comment: i am using java j2EE spring mvc framework for server side...but request is hitting to the server but parameters values are null as i described.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831680/httpservletrequest-get-json-post-data  you are sending json data which you can't read directly as form-data.

Comment: https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Axios is sending Json data you will not be able to read its direct. 
There are 2 possible solutions:

1. Either send data as form-data.
2. Read & Parse JSON at servlet:

   ```
   public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
                                         throws ServletException, IOException {    
       StringBuffer jb = new StringBuffer();
       String line = null;
       try {
           BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
           while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
               jb.append(line);
           }
       } catch (Exception e) { /*report an error*/ }

       try {
           JSONObject jsonObject =  HTTP.toJSONObject(jb.toString());
           String price = jsonObject.get("price"); // will return price value.
       } catch (JSONException e) {
           throw new IOException("Error parsing JSON request string");
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: from this line JSONObject jsonObject = HTTP.toJSONObject(jb.toString()); how to import JSONObject  and HTTP ?? these are giving

Comment: You need to import corresponding jars.. `org.json`  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json for json object

Comment: String price = jsonObject.get("price");  this line giving error as jsonObject.get("price") is not saving to price

Comment: i have done it from littlebit different method...but you gave me idea that axios sending json data so i am able to complete it dat is why i am accepting your answer...

Answer (score 1):

Request Body is not retrieved by request.getParameter(). You need to retrieve it by request.getReader().

```
String body = IOUtils.toString(request.getReader());
```

It is suggested to use **Apache Commons IO** to get Content first. As your request is in JSON format. You can use **Jackson** to convert the String into Map.

```
Map<String, String> map = mapper.readValue(body, new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>(){});
System.out.println(map.get("item"));
System.out.println(map.get("price"));
```

Answer (score 0):

`request.getParameter()`is referring to URL **parameters** ->`myurl?someparameter=1`

By doing `request.getParameter("item")`, your URL would need to look like `http://localhost:8080/SampleJavaAPP/UserServer?item=myitem`

What you are actually doing here

```
sendData(data,price) {
    axios.post('http://localhost:8080/SampleJavaAPP/UserServer', {
    item: data,//these value
    price:price//these value
}
```

is adding the objects to the request body, which is IMHO correct. There for you won't find any parameters `item` or `price` on your server side request object.

What you need to do, is to parse the requests body. With `request.getInputStream()` you can get the `Inputstream`. I suggest you use an object mapper which makes that really easy. See [Intro to the Jackson ObjectMapper](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial)

In your servlet, you do something like this:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyItem myItem = objectMapper.readValue(request.getInputStream(), MyItem.class);

public class MyItem{

    String price;
    String item;

    public void setItem(String item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

}
```

Comment: where should i call request.getBody() ??

Comment: Usually in your servlet. The same location where you did the call `request.getParameter`

Comment: My bad. It's not `request.getBody()` check my updated answer

Comment: i am not getting properly what you are trying to say....should i call String price = request.getInputStream("price") ??? i called it but it gives me error.

Comment: A request body is available as an InputStream (See [InputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html)), which of course is not castable directly to one of your objects. What you need to do, is to convert this `InputStream` to your objects. For this you will use the object mapper.