# How to send Javascript multidimensional array values to Java servlet?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, servlets

I have store the textbox's value to the multidimensional array in Javascript named as records (below code) and I need to send these array object to my servlet page. But I have no idea about how to get the complete array data.

### Javascript code

```
function insert(row,col){   
var r = row, c=col; 
var q = new Array(); 
for(i=0; i<r; i++){
    q[i] = new Array(); 
    for(j=0; j<c; j++){
    var pick = "#"+i+j;  // select the id's of textbox 
    q[i][j] = $(pick).val(); // store the textbox value to array
    }
  }
 $.ajax({
    url: 'Insert',
    type: 'post',
    data: {records : q, row: r,field: c },   // need to send the records array
    success: function(result){
        console.log(result);
    }
 });
}
```

### Java code

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
 response) throws ServletException, IOException {

 PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
// need to get the javascript array. but HOW ? 
}
```

Comment: Well, first you need to decide on which HTTP method to use. `type: 'post'` vs `doGet` doesn't match.

Comment: yes ! i know , I call doGet method by doPost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't send an object like that using Ajax, use [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to create a JSON string, e.g.

```
data: JSON.stringify({records : q, row: r,field: c }),
```

*And as commented, decide which HTTP method to use, as if Ajax is of type `post` the servlet won't catch it with a `doGet`.*

---

Updated

Here is a good answer, showing a `doPost` in more detail

- [HttpServletRequest get JSON POST data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831680/httpservletrequest-get-json-post-data/3831791#3831791)

Comment: Ok , how can i get this JSON string in servlets ?

Comment: @SandyKrish Updated with a great link/answer

Comment: Thanks its really help full, but i have another, this JSON.stringify() convert the object to string format but i need to convert as array in java, how can i convert . It totally print as string like this   OUTPUT : [["HAI","I","AM","SANDY"],["HOW","DO","YOU","DO"]]     I need to split this string to array again.

Comment: @SandyKrish Check the link in my answer, it shows how-to using something like `JSONObject jsonObject =  HTTP.toJSONObject(jb.toString());`