# jquery post to PhishTank

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery and have been trying to query the [PhishTank API](http://www.phishtank.com/api_info.php) and in Firebug it returns the url in red and nothing was returned from PhishTank. The code I used is below.

`$(document).ready(function() { $.post("http://checkurl.phishtank.com/checkurl/", { url: "http://google.com" }, alert(data)); });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to refer you to this question from yesterday. The top answer (from me) should explain the ins and outs.

Basically, the problem is the XHR Cross Domain Policy - you can't use XHR cross domain. Two ways to solve this, JSONP (which is GET only, basically injects a `script` tag. jQuery supports this natively) or build a "proxy" script on your own domain that forwards the request and returns the response to your script. Both are explained in a little more detail in my answer in the added link.

- [Odd jQuery problem - Ajax request to a C program not quite working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831255/odd-jquery-problem-ajax-request-to-a-c-program-not-quite-working)

Cross-Domain POST requests don't work, unless you build a proxy script. So it's JSONP with a GET request (if supported by your webservice), or a proxy script.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do cross-domain requests.  See "Additional Notes" section: [jQuery.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)